# passing params around from one page to another ruby on rails helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have devise installed on a student model

in a index.html.haml page I have a view like this

```
  .span10
    -@brands.each do |brand|
      .row
        .span4.text-center
          =image_tag brand.image_url if brand.image?
        .span2
          %h2=brand.name
        .span4{style: "position:relative; height: 200px; text-align:center;"}
          Requirements
          %h5=brand.requirement
          %div{style: "position: absolute; bottom: 40px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%;"}
          =link_to t('slide2.apply_here'), new_student_registration_path(:brand => brand.id),class: "button-component", style: "font-size: 14px; padding: 10px 50px;"
```

please focus on the link_to

I am passing the brand id to the new_student_registration path

here is my student registration controller

```
class Students::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/events/new'
    brand #working on 
  end 

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path(resource)
    '/events/new'
    brand #working on 
  end 

  def brand
    id = params[:brand]
    @brand = Brand.find(id)
  end 
  helper_method :brand 
end
```

I have a brand helper method which grabs the params from the link_to and I am using it to find a specific brand.

I passed it to the sign up page in the view to render a picture on the model

```
.row
  .span4
    .accordion#picture_accordion.left
    =image_tag brand.image_url
    %h3=brand.name
```

I have this in my application controller

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    '/events/new'
  end
```

after someone sign in or sign up I am directing them to `events/new`

what I want is to pass the brand to events/new! so I can drop this again into events/new

```
.row
  .span4
    .accordion#picture_accordion.left
    =image_tag brand.image_url
    %h3=brand.name
```

I keep on looking at my registrations controller, how do I pass in the return value of my helper method to my after sign up path methods? I feel like this can work. However I am not sure how to pass in that same return value of my helper method to the after sign in method in my application controller?

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: A non-negligeable improvement would be `brand ||= Brand.find(params[:brand])` : The double pipes `||` before the equal means if the variable is alrady set, it won't be set again. Which means if you call `brand` multiple times, it will set only once the `@brand`, which means it will generate only one SQL query (right now it is querying the DB each time you call `brand`)

Comment: use a session variable for that

Comment: @phoet can I add this into my brand method? `session[:brand] = Brand.find params[:brand]` its my first time using session.

Comment: best thing would be to add the `params[:brand]` to your session. session objects should be as small as possible (ids).